# Pointing arrows from two sentences to a word

Tags: beamer, arrows, nodes, text

I am using beamer to create slides. I am not sure how to generate arrows from two sentences merging and pointing towards a word as shown in the below image.

[image]

Comment: The method used here [How to format table with long column head entries?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/12979) can be adapted to this use. There are other questions that answer similar problems. See answers using the `tikzmark` package. [How to use tikzmark to label steps in math mode with fractions?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/525075) or [Arrows with tikz between words in beamer](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/625647) or [How to place right brace next to table row](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/412953) or [Annotating Tables With Tikz; Adding Arrows](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/167000) among others.

Answer (score 5):

This approach uses tikz and, in particular, referencing nodes outside the current picture (§17.13 of the [manual](https://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), v.3.1.9a).
I will first present the idea and then refactor it to be simpler to use.

At the end of each sentence, there is an invisible node (`s1` and `s2`). There's also an invisible node (`e1` and `e2`) at the right margin. We then make a node (`w`) with the "Word", midway between the nodes `e1` and `e2`. We also make a coordinate (`p`) that is 1cm to the left of the word's left side. The arrows connect the node `s1` (respectively, `s2`) to `w` via `p`, with perpendicular lines.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{phantom/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Big sentence 1 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      \tikz[baseline=(s1.base),remember picture] \node[phantom] (s1) {\strut}; \hfill
      \tikz[baseline=(e1.base),remember picture] \node[phantom] (e1) {\strut};
\item Big sentence 2 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      \tikz[baseline=(s2.base),remember picture] \node[phantom] (s2) {\strut}; \hfill
      \tikz[baseline=(e2.base),remember picture] \node[phantom] (e2) {\strut};
\end{itemize}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \path (e1) -- (e2) node[midway,anchor=east] (w) {Word}
        (w.west) +(left:1cm) coordinate (p);
  \draw[-Stealth] (s1) -| (p) |- (w.west);
  \draw[-Stealth] (s2) -| (p) |- (w.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is the following:
[image: Result]

With a little refactoring, this approach can be structured around two commands: `\setpoint{p}` for marking the end of a sentence as point `p`, and `\mergepoints{p}{q}{Word}` for drawing an arrow merging points `p` and `q` to the given word.

```
\newcommand\setpoint[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(s#1.base),remember picture] \node[phantom] (s#1) {\strut};
  \hfill
  \tikz[baseline=(e#1.base),remember picture] \node[phantom] (e#1) {\strut};
}
\newcommand{\mergepoints}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \path (e#1) -- (e#2) node[midway,anchor=east] (w) {#3}
          (w.west) +(left:1cm) coordinate (p);
    \draw[-Stealth] (s#1) -| (p) |- (w.west);
    \draw[-Stealth] (s#2) -| (p) |- (w.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Then, the same example can be drawn as:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Big sentence 1 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \setpoint{1}
  \item Big sentence 2 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \setpoint{2}
\end{itemize}
\mergepoints{1}{2}{Word}
\end{frame}
```

In fact, this can be used to construct more complex instances of the same idea, e.g.

```
\begin{frame}
Two sentences:
\begin{itemize}
  \item Big sentence 1 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \setpoint{1}
  \item Small sentence 1 aaaaaaaaa \setpoint{2}
\end{itemize}
and two more:
\begin{itemize}
  \item Big sentence 2 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \setpoint{3}
  \item Small sentence 2 aaaaaaa \setpoint{4}
\end{itemize}
\mergepoints{1}{3}{Big}
\mergepoints{2}{4}{Small}
\end{frame}
```

which gives the following:
[image: More involved example]